# What's the meaning of the error proto.014-PtKathma.tez.subtraction_underflow?

Tags: rpc, error, nft

I have a question about the RPC error `proto.014-PtKathma.tez.subtraction_underflow` sent by the node when I tried to generate a NFT on the Tezos blockchain with pytezos.

The full error:

```
Received RpcError: ({'amounts': ['10209', '16750'], 'id': 'proto.014-PtKathma.tez.subtraction_underflow', 'kind': 'temporary'},)
```

I understand that the left value is lower than the right value and this is why the error is triggered but I don't understand where those values came from.

The request works after few retries (with different wallets but it seems this is not linked to it) so it is not critical but I would like to understand the meaning of this error to avoid the creation of new errors of the same type.

I have found a beginning of explanation [here](https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/errors.html) but the website give to too few informations to permits me to understand.

If someone could give me more explanations, I would be very grateful about it (I'm newbie about development on Tezos. Sorry, if my question is a bit... simple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some moment during the application of the operation, an operation `A - B` on two mutez amounts is performed, but the result is negative. The function that did the subtraction then threw that error.

Imagine for instance you have 80000 mutez in your balance, and that you should pay 50000 mutez for burn (to mint the token and store it in the smart contract) and 40000 mutez as fees to the baker. Doing `r1 = 80000 mutez -  50000 mutez` and then `r2 = r1 - 40000 mutez` will underflow (`r2 = -10000`). The error is returned because you cannot have negative balances.

Comment: OK I understand for this part. Thank you for your answer.

However, I have a question with this calcul: I have two mint which are done in the same condition for both (same wallet, same contract, same target wallet).
The first try not work (with the error substraction_underflow) and the second one work.

Is there a variable value in burn or fee to the baker value ?

Comment: It depends on a lot of parameters and you didn't provide enough information to answer :-)  (a) Do you use eg. a wallet, tezos-client or taquito to mint, (b) it depends on the smart contract, ...